# Jquery- fetch checkbox selected values and save it to cookies at modal close button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, modalpopups

Spent almost two days trying to figure out this problem. I have modal popup with dynamic checbox list (generated from database) and close button on modal popup. What I want is that when user click 'Close' button, then modal popup is closed but the same time I want to get all selected checboxes values to save in string.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnHide" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClick="btnHide_Click" OnClientClick="HideModalPopup()"/>

protected void btnHide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           string names=checkCheckboxes(); //calling WORKING function which reutrns all selected checboxes from modal popup in a string, splited by comma
           Response.Write(names); //trying to write 'names' variabile which contains all selected checboxes on screen
        }
```

jQuery function:

```
function HideModalPopup() {
    $find("mpe").hide();
    return false;
}
```

Problem is that when I click close button, modal popup disapeared, but no values are saved to variabile 'names' in btnHide_Click method. How can I get selected checkboxes from modal popup to this function? What is wrong with this code?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via ajax call. In your clientside function where you hide modal box before that fetch all the checkbox checked value using .each()  jquery n then call ajax request and save it to ur database.

```
function HideModalPopup() { 
     var fetchAllChkbox= $("input[name=chkboxName]:ch ecked").map( function () {return this.value;}).get().join(",");

         $find("mpe").hide(); 
        // $.ajax  call to save to database etc
        return false;
     }
```

Note- herechkboxName is name of chkboxss,

---

**Updated Answer :** Get all selected checkbox values in a variable and create cookie session and set selected value to it.

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#clkme").click(function () {
        var getValue = ""; // get vall checkbox selected values
        $("[id*=CheckBoxList1] input:checked").each(function () {
        var Value = $(this).val();
        getValue += Value + ",";
        });
       $.cookie('your_cookie_name', getValue); // set cookies
       alert($.cookie('your_cookie_name')); // read cookies and alert it
    });
  });
```

**HTml markup:**

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
  <div id="clkme">CLICK ME</div>
```

Note: just import this cookie.js https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: I need to write 'names' variabile to cookie "via" method btnHide_Click. Is it even possible?

Comment: Yes loop over checkbox and fetch vaules save in a variable or set to hidden field. This can be done frm client side , later if u wnt u can save to database with ajax call , in ajax you can pass those parameter amd on serverside getthose value

Comment: Ok, now I need to figure it out checbox names, because now every checbox have a different name beacuse of checboxlist. 
First checkbox - ctl00$CheckBoxList1$1, second-ctl00$CheckBoxList1$2, etc..

Comment: Anyway, when I get this var fetchAllChkBox, how can I write this value to cookie? I do not want to include more plugins to jquery..

Comment: You can grab the selected checkbox values with jQuery. You can find an example here http://techbrij.com/checkboxlist-jquery-asp-net-operations

Comment: Thanks David! All I need is on this link!